# Sum of Integers Using a List

Tags: scala

I've been trying to finish this scala code that uses a list to output the summation of all positive integers in the list.. I got it working except for having it only work for positive numbers. but i cant get it to only output the positive numbers. I have 2 versions that ive been trying to get to work, i thought maybe it would be easier wit cases, but i ended up running into the same problem. I've been trying if statements with xs<0 , but those don't work, and i cant get the filter to work with the fold. any suggestions with how to handle this?

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {

xs.filter((x: Int) => x > 0)

xs.foldLeft(0) { _ + _ }

}

def sum2(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {

case Nil => 0
case y :: ys => y + sum(ys)
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that xs.filter doesn't modify xs but returns a new list. So you want to chain it xs.filter(...).foldLeft(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 1st version is almost right. Remember that filter method doesn't have side effects, so just try this small change:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {    
  xs.filter((x: Int) => x > 0).foldLeft(0) { _ + _ }    
}
```

Or simpler version:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  xs.filter(_ > 0).sum
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`xs` is an immutable `List[Int]`, which means you are *not* just modifying the same `xs` value and returning it.

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    xs.filter((x: Int) => x > 0) // This is a pure expression and effectively does nothing
    xs.foldLeft(0) { _ + _ }     // This is the value that is returned, modifying the *original* `xs` parameter
}
```

What you need to do is chain the functions together, to operate on the same value.

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    xs.filter((x: Int) => x > 0).foldLeft(0) { _ + _ }
}
```

The type check isn't necessary here, so it can be shorted:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs.filter(_ > 0).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
```

There is also a `sum` method on `List` that does the same thing as your `foldLeft`.

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs.filter(_ > 0).sum
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List(1, -2, 3).filter(_ > 0).sum // 4
```

or in a single pass

```
List(1, -2, 3).foldLeft(0){(acc, i) => if (i > 0) acc + i else acc } //4
```

Answer (score 0):

i ended up trying this , which i think is right. based on the suggestions

```
 val f = xs.filter((x: Int) => x > 0)

 f.foldLeft(0) { _ + _ }
```